# Sending SMS via AT Command's & bluetooth doesn't work in C++

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, winsock, at-command

I'm creating an application which provide all function's like phone device from PC.

Phone is connected with PC via bluetooth and winsock, dial number with AT command ATD work's fine, but all other's command's look's like that:

```
BTMobileApp DEBUG: WINSOCK: 'send' Return Code: 0

BTMobileApp DEBUG:    Bytes Sent: AT+CMGL

BTMobileApp DEBUG: WINSOCK: 'recv' Return Code: 0

BTMobileApp DEBUG:    Data Received: 

+CME ERROR: 0
```

Return error code mean's

> Phone failure

Syntax of AT command's (/r | /n) is correct for sure. Don't know where could be the problem.

Here's the important part of code:

```
SOCKADDR_BTH RemoteEndPoint;
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
RemoteEndPoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = // BT device address
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID;
int BTHAddrLength = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);

// Create the socket.
if ((m_localSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}

// Connect the socket.
if ((iResult = connect(m_localSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&RemoteEndPoint, sizeof(RemoteEndPoint))) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}

char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
const char *sendbuf = "AT+CMGL\r";
int len = (int)strlen(sendbuf);
if ((iResult = send(m_localSocket, sendbuf, len, MSG_OOB)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error.
}

if ((iResult = recv(m_localSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error.
}
```

-- Could anybody give me some advice how to make that AT command's work?

I'm trying to solve this about two week's and i'm kinda exhausted of solving that.
Thank you.

Comment: Is it just SMS related commands that fail, or is `ATD` the only that works? Try to run `AT+CLAC` which should list all available AT command. Try most/all of them to get a feeling of what work/does not work.

Comment: I would say 50/50, some of them works's, some of them don't. For example `ATD, AT+CLIP, AT+CHUP, ... ` work's but SMS related, deleting or creating new contact in phonebook fail's. Unfortunately `AT+CLAC` return's ERROR aswell :/

Comment: Notice that SMS commands operate relative to a storage selected with `AT+CPMS`. What values does `AT+CPMS=?` return and does sms commands fail for all or them? Similarly for phonebook there is the select phonebook storage command `AT+CPBS`.

Comment: Choosing SMS storage fail's, but choosing phonebook storage doesn't fail and i can read all contact's and call history, but command's for creating/removing contact like `AT+CPBW=,”6187759088″,129,”Adam”` fail. :/ It is strange.